# Android ProgressDialog no longer visible after another application pushes my activity away

Tags: android, progressdialog

Let's say I have 2 running applications A & B on an API level 8 device.

From A, I start an activity which starts a long running unzip process (let's say about 4 gigs). I show the progress of this in a ProgressDialog.

In the meantime, by manual action, an action causes B to respond and push the activity with the ProgressDialog away from the screen (onStop is called).
I perform some actions and when I am done I hide the activity of B. 
So that the activity of A appears back on the screen (onResume is called).

However the ProgressDialog is gone, even though the long running process is still running. How did my ProgressDialog disappear after the OnStop was called and why doesn't it come back in my OnResume?

---

Presumably the context of the activity has changed and thus the ProgressDialog who was called with the context of the activity is gone as well. But since the long running process is still running and in working order I should be able to get the same instance of the ProgressDialog as well.
However just calling .show() will not work.

Mind that the functionality is just working fine within a single application. It is purely problematic when 2 applications are fighting eachother.

Answer (score 0):

Dialogs alone are not kept between state restores, if you want the system to restore a Dialog you need to use a DialogFragment.

Comment: Problem with this is that we cannot allow them because we still accept API level 8 devices (don't ask me why...). Adjusted the question.

Comment: Then you need to in OnSaveInstanceState check if your dialog is shown, if so save that boolean in the bundle, then OnCreate/onRestoreInstanceState read that boolean and recreate the dialog. Also to avoid memory leaks hide the dialog in onPause and show it in onResume

Comment: That wouldn't work because the OnCreate/onRestoreInstanceState are not triggered. The activity is not build from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a broadcast from your unzip process, and in the activity you register a broadcast receiver that shows a dialog with the progress.

If you would like to go with the dialog fragment approach, you can use the [support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/package-summary.html) which is backward compatible with earlier Android versions

or just show hide your dialog depending on the activity life cycle like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog mDialog;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
mDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);

}
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mDialog.show();
    }
@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mDialog.hide();
    }
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mDialog!=null){
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mm, i hadn't thought of that yet. A localbroadcast could deliver the progression i need properly. I will give it a try.

Comment: I am getting similar issues with this solution. The progressDialog still claims to exist and claims it isShowing() on screen. Adding the support library is not an option also since I have to stay in the old wicked ugly programming style of the current solution (to my big regret). The context of the progressdialog doesn't seem to match the one that I am comparing it with either. Since the progressdialog seems to be showing but is covered by the old restarted activity. Shouldn't I try to make it appear to the foreground again? I wasn't able to thus far but still...

Comment: That is the standard way of showing dialogs. Unfortunately this does not work for this situation either. The problem is that the context of the ProgressDialog is not updated to the correct one after the OnStop -> OnRestart -> OnStart -> OnResume cycle. So that when the activity pops back on top and has it's context updated the ProgressDialog still remains below. Perhaps I should just write a custom extension of the ProgressDialog with as addition a function to update the Context, but I'm not sure that will work either.

Comment: You just need to keep track of your progress value, either by sending it in broadcasts or storing it somewhere and retrieving it in your activity's onResume

Comment: The progressvalue is not the problem since the unzip process is one that calculates this value. If my app with progressdialog goes to the background (homescreen) and comes back by accessing it via the notificationbar there is no problem with the progressdialog.